# TensorRT for python on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, openpose

I'm having problems using TensorRT for python on windows.

I want to use openpose on windows however it requires TensorRT for python. when I'm trying to execute file run_webcam.py (openpose code), I have the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt"
```

I installed tensorflow package (last version) but it doesn't contain tensorrt class
Looking for a solution, I found the following information on nvidia website https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044414/tensorrt/tensorrt-python-and-windows/

How does OpenPose work on windows if windows doesn't support TensorRT for python?????

Any tips or help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi @Edna Salazar. As far as I know, the [official OpenPose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose) does not use TensorFlow and TensorRT, and uses Caffe instead, which works on Windows. Are you using the official OpenPose, or one of the many third-party clones?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am concerned, the TensorRT python API is not supported in Windows as per the [official TensorRT documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html#gettingstarted):

> *The Windows zip package for TensorRT does not provide Python support.
>   Python may be supported in the future*

I am having the same problem for the inference in Windows systems. I was using TRT for inference in python, and it works like a charm... in Linux. We are already in TRT 7.0 release and still no plans of supporting the python API in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is official support for TensorRT Python API under windows.
Have a look at the comment from NVIDIA moderator on the following issue:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/1080#issuecomment-1038685416

To check the compatibility of the different versions of TensorRT, Tensorflow, cuDNN, and other libraries, visit the link:
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/support-matrix/index.html